# Encouraging box2d to favour rotation of bodies on collision

Tags: box2d

I want to create asteroids that are irregularly shaped polygons which land on various hills and then roll down them. An issue I have ran into was that the polygons often bounce around a bit, however, they do not roll as much as I would hope. Should I just be modifying the torque post collision linearly(which I seem to do badly), or is there something in Box2d that I can turn up to encourage more rotation than normal?

Comment: Both the ground and the asteroids would need to have a high friction. If you haven't changed the default value you could try that because the default friction is very low.

Answer (score 0):

Create forces pushing horizontally toward valley points. They should only be active while the asteroid is in contact with the ground, and should shut off at a certain depth as to avoid the asteroid rolling back and forth at the bottom. It's skewing the simulation a bit, but it may be what you want.